# SQL Server 2005: Full-text search catalog design

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, full-text-search

I'm new to full-text searches, and am curious about how to properly design the full-text catalogs.  I have an "articles" table.  I would like to do full-text search on both the "title" and the "body" at the same time.

Does this require two separate catalogs?  If not, is it better to use two separate catalogs, or just one?  If another unrelated table requires full-text indexing, should it be part of the same catalog, or a different one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just asked a Microsoft Certified Trainer during [a developer course for SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/Course.aspx?ID=10776A&Locale=en-us).  He suggested using a single catalog, and having the two indexes, "title" and "body" in the same catalog.

The only thing to watch is with too many indexes in the same catalog, there is a greater chance for fragmentation within the catalog.  With two columns though, this should not be a concern.